# How can I check more than two conditions inside oncomplete

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, if-statement, xhtml

I have 4 conditions to check, I want to check it inside oncomplete statement.
I recognized that I can check only two using if else. 
If I use if -> else if -> else if -> else if to check 4 conditions in oncomplete.
When I did that it can check only if and else if (again 2 conditions only) 
Is any way to check more than two conditions?
That's my code. That code can check only if and 1st else if

```
<a4j:commandLink .....
action ....
oncomplete=" if (1st condtition ) ; else if (2nd condition) ; else if (3th condition ) ; else if (4th condition)"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @Svennx3 remove **else's** from your code !

Comment: Can you not just use `&&` `(x == x && y == y)` ?

Comment: if i remove else's from my code it will check 4 condtitions, but also it will return me 4 statements. And i have to click 4 times ok cuz i get 4 pop up windows :D I want to have only one final statement, not 4

Comment: @svennnx3 Can you provide a more complete example, because your description is very abstract and doesn't make it clear what the intended result is. For all I know, you are looking for `switch`.

Comment: I find out an answear for my own question. I will explain that in the answear of it.
But i will explain my problem more properly for you and all guys who will read it anytime. So:
I have a .xhtml file , where i am using Seam framework and JSF to connect front-end and back-end side of my project.
Also i am using AJAX. 
I have the <a4j:commandLink> which is containing in body : onclick , action , oncomplete , rendered .
So in oncomplete i wanted to check 4 different condtitions , depends of result i wanted to call an method from some java class. 
But oncomplete supports only if else.

Comment: And i wanted to use if else if , else if , else if. It not gonna work unfrotunately. So i only did 2 condtitions ( if and else). my methods just set 2 boolean variables. Then i am calling to show an dialog window when my booleans are true. That solves my problem, to show two dialogs at once or only 1 when only one variable is true :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out an answear for my own question. I will explain that in the answear of it. But i will explain my problem more properly for you and all guys who will read it anytime. So: I have a .xhtml file , where i am using Seam framework and JSF to connect front-end and back-end side of my project. Also i am using AJAX. I have the  which is containing in body : onclick , action , oncomplete , rendered . So in oncomplete i wanted to check 4 different condtitions , depends of result i wanted to call an method from some java class. But oncomplete supports only if else. – svennnx3 3 mins ago    Edit
And i wanted to use if else if , else if , else if. It not gonna work unfrotunately. So i only did 2 condtitions ( if and else). my methods just set 2 boolean variables. Then i am calling to show an dialog window when my booleans are true. That solves my problem, to show two dialogs at once or only 1 when only one variable is true :)

Answer (score 0):

If u want to check for `true`

```
if(1st condition && 2nd condition && 3rd condition && 4th condition){}
```

or any one `true`

```
if(1st condition || 2nd condition || 3rd condition || 4th condition){}
```

Comment: I want to check for condtitions, because every one condtition has statement connected to it. For example, user is choosing country, and my website should get continent in return for me.

Comment: u can use switch statement for it

Comment: how can i use switch statement in oncomplete?

Comment: I don't know how to implement that into my oncomplete. Because every if have action connected to it - depends of result of my if condtition, like:
oncomplete="if (condtion == true) dosomething, else if (condtiton2=true) dosomethingelse

Comment: `switch (condtion == true) {
    case "india":
        // Blah
        break;
    case "usa":
        // Blah
        break;
}`